# assign a data frame as csv header

Tags: r, csv

In R, I want to import a CSV without header, however column(attribute) names are saved in another data frame. how can I import the CSV with data frame as header? Here is the example, see the comments for more details

```
library('visNetwork') 
# nodes contain names of read.csv col which are col1 to col4    
id=c("col1", "col12", "col13", "col14") 
nodes=data.frame(id)
#data.csv doesnt have the header, I want to assign nodes as it header
links <- read.csv("data.csv", header=F)
# next command doesnt work properly, because r imported csv with defaults names(V1 to V4) which doesn't match names assigned in nodes
visNetwork(nodes, links, width="100%", height="400px", main="graph example")
```

Comment: May be I'm a bit dense, or your terminology is not well aligned with mine. Do you mean to say that levels in column `attribute` are stored in another data.frame?

Comment: What I mean is header names of CSV are stored in another data frame. people sometimes call header name attributes or column's name. CSV doesnt have the header so I need to import it manually.

Comment: Why don't you just do this: `names(links) <- id`

Comment: works great. didnt know about assigining name with `names`